# How do I retrieve an item from a Vec that is moved into a structure?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a structure which contains a Vector of structs, e.g.

```
fn main() {
    let x: Vec<Item> = Vec::new(); 
    // assume x is filled with stuff
    do_things_with(x);
}

struct Item {
    value: String,
}

struct Context {
    x: Vec<Item>,
}

impl Context {
    fn get(&mut self, at: usize) -> Item {
        self.x[at]
    }
}

fn do_things_with(x: Vec<Item>) {
    let mut ctx = Context{
        x: x,
    };
    ctx.get(5);
}
```

I have a Vec of stuff, and I pass this to some function which creates a context and stores the passed value in that structure. I then want to look at the items in this Vec so I have some helper functions, e.g. 'get' which will get the item at the index specified.

This seems all good, and in C or whatever language it would be fine, however Rust complains:

```
'cannot move out of borrowed content'
```

For the function 'get' where we try to access the item in the vector.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Vec` has ownership of the `Item`s it contains, but `Context.get` is trying to return the `Item` directly (and take ownership of it).

If `Context.get` just needs to let callers peek at the contents of the vector, it should return a reference to an Item instead of an Item:

```
impl Context {
    fn get(&mut self, at: usize) -> &Item {
        &self.x[at]
    }
}
```

In the above case, `Context.get` can take an immutable reference to `self` since it is not changing anything. Further, if you want to allow callers of `Context.get` to modify the referenced Item, you would return `&mut Item` instead of `&Item`:

```
impl Context {
    fn get(&mut self, at: usize) -> &mut Item {
        &mut self.x[at]
    }
}
```

Edit: As @apemanzilla helpfully notes in the comments, you could also have Item implement the `Clone` trait if you want Context.get to return a separate copy of the Item at `at`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Item {
    value: String,
}

impl Context {
    fn get(&mut self, at: usize) -> Item {
        self.x[at].clone()
    }
```

Changing the returned Item will not modify the one contained in self.x though; this may or may not be what you intended.

Comment: I'd also add a note about using the `Clone` or `Copy` trait for small types.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. What is preferred: making a clone of something, or having an immutable borrow of it. Note that in the context the item wont be modified.

Comment: @flooblebit Cloning is potentially expensive. You should be cloning if your intention is "I want a separate copy this thing which I can modify without changing the original". If you aren't changing the original, prefer immutable refs; if you are changing the original, prefer a mutable ref.